# Chrome failed to start in GitHub Actions

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, pytest, github-actions

This is the error message I get from GitHub workflows:

`/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:76: in __init__ 47 RemoteWebDriver.__init__( 48 /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:157: in __init__ 49 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile) 50 /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:252: in start_session 51 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters) 52 /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute 53 self.error_handler.check_response(response)`

`response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited a...wn>\\n#14 0x563a8d1c9e58 \\u003Cunknown>\\n#15 0x563a8d1e3dfd \\u003Cunknown>\\n#16 0x7f9599f6f609 start_thread\\n"}}'}`

Note: I am using webdriver manager to install chrome driver.

Comment: Could you share the Github Action workflow you used in your question please? As well as the implementation used for the chrome driver setup 